# Append items to a ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I would like to append new items to a ListView to enable endless scrolling.

```
private ListAdapter adapter;
ArrayList < HashMap < String, String >> listViewList;

...

class GetItems extends AsyncTask < String, String, String > {

    protected String doInBackground(String...args) {
        ...

        for (int i = 0; i < items.length(); i++) {
            ...
            HashMap < String, String > map = new HashMap < String, String > ();
            map.put("name_1", name_1);
            map.put("name_2", name_3);
            map.put("name_3", name_3);

            listViewList.add(map);
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        adapter = new CustomAdapter(Activity.this, listViewList,
            R.layout.single_item, new String[] {}, new int[] {});
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

`GetItems` class gets new items based on a page number you provide. I would like to append new items to existing ListView items on `onPostExecute`.

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this library on GitHub

- https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews

EDIT according to your comment:

You need to forget about `ListActivity` and that you ever heard it exists, it's useless for what you are trying to do.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;



public class DemosAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public List<DemoItem> listOfItems;
    private View v;
    private ViewWrapper wrapper;
    private Context context;

    public DemosAdapter(Context c, List<DemoItem> listOfItems) {
        this.context = c;
        this.listOfItems = listOfItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listOfItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public DemoItem getItem(int i) {
        return listOfItems.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    public void sort() {
        Collections.sort(listOfItems, new Comparator<DemoItem>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(DemoItem item, DemoItem item2) {
                return item.getName().compareTo(item2.getName());
            }
        });
    }

    public void addItems(List<DemoItem> listOfFreshItems){
        listOfItems.addAll(listOfFreshItems);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        DemoItem itm = listOfItems.get(position);

        v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.demo_item, null, false);
            wrapper = new ViewWrapper(v);
            v.setTag(wrapper);
        }
        else {
            wrapper = (ViewWrapper) v.getTag();
        }

        wrapper.getTvDemoName().setText(itm.getName());

        return v;
    }

    private class ViewWrapper {

        private View base;
        private TextView tvDemoName;

        public ViewWrapper(View v) {
            this.base = v;
        }

        public TextView getTvDemoName() {
            if (tvDemoName == null) {
                tvDemoName = (TextView) base.findViewById(R.id.tvDemoName);
            }
            return tvDemoName;
        }

    }
}
```

The first time you add data, do this

```
demosAdapter = new DemosAdapter(this, listOfDemos);
demosAdapter.sort();
lvListOfDemos.setAdapter(demosAdapter);
```

When you get new items, just call

```
adapter.addItems(List<DemoItem> newItems);
```

Comment: I've already seen it, but it doesn't show how to append new data items to adapter.

Comment: I have added some demo code. You will need to modify it according to your need, but you will see the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you just need to call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged` in `onPostExecute`. 
But you should not instantiate adapter many times. It should  be done just one so overall it would look like this

```
private ListAdapter adapter;

...
void onCreate(){ // assuming this is an activity
   adapter = new CustomAdapter(Activity.this, listViewList,
             R.layout.single_item, new String[] {}, new int[] {});
   setListAdapter(adapter);
}

class GetItems extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
  ...  

   protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
}
```

Comment: adapter doesn't have notifyDataSetChanged(), only notify() and notifyAll().

Comment: No because ListAdapter is just an interface. The implementation depends on your CustomAdapter. Although technically you can add items to list the adapter is associated with but without said implementation it would be impossible for the change to take effect.